# Find the time hogger during Ubuntu boot process

Tags: linux, ubuntu, amazon-ec2

My EC2 (Ubuntu 12.04 server) took about 1 min to boot (defined as the time between power-on and all the daemon processes are started).  I need to cut down the time to boot. My guess is that the total time depends on kernel boot time and the time to start all the daemons.

Kernel doesn't seem to take much time (the following is from my kern.log) and it showed it didn't take about 14sec.  I am curious if any of the daemons are taking a long time. Wonder if there is a log that has the timestamps for each daemon, from which I can infer the time hoggers.

```
May 25 21:41:44 ip-172-31-18-129 kernel: [23567315.531742] Built 1 zonelists in Node order, mobility grouping on.  Total pages: 156595
...
May 25 21:41:52 ip-172-31-18-129 kernel: [23567329.848700] eth0: no IPv6 routers present
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/BootCharting allows you to see what takes the time in booting.

There is also an old thread here on various things you might try: https://askubuntu.com/questions/10290/how-do-i-improve-boot-speed

Comment: Thanks @mc110 for the link. It's Ubuntu server (hence no GUI). Are there any packages/software that can be used to analyze the timing? Thanks!